# How to change Machine Precision digits to meet the tolerances

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, special-functions, nonlinear, machine-precision

I am trying to solve for Tcm and Mag by solving nonlinear equations using FindRoot command using following code:

```
Tc0 = 1;
rg = Rationalize@0.057375;
ratio = Rationalize@0.1;
\[CapitalGamma]0 = rg 2 \[Pi] Tc0;
\[CapitalGamma]p = ratio \[CapitalGamma]0;
\[CapitalGamma]t  =  \[CapitalGamma]0 + \[CapitalGamma]p;
nMax  = 10000;
Ts = Rationalize@1.02758;
Tc = Rationalize@0.942857;

(*Fourth order algebraic equation for gwn*)
{sol1[n_, Mag_, Tcm_] , sol2[n_, Mag_, Tcm_]  , sol3[n_, Mag_, Tcm_]  , 
   sol4[n_, Mag_, Tcm_]  } = 
  gwn /. Solve[
    1/gwn^2 == 1 + Mag^2/((2 n + 1) Pi Tcm + 2 \[CapitalGamma]t  gwn )^2, 
    gwn];  

(*Equation for Tcm*)
sumArg4Tcm[n_, Mag_, Tcm_]  = 
  2 Pi Tcm (2 n + 
     1) Pi Tcm (sol4[n, Mag, Tcm ] - 1)/((2 n + 1) Pi Tcm +  
       2 \[CapitalGamma]p )/((2 n + 1) Pi Tcm + 
      2 \[CapitalGamma]p  sol4[n, Mag, Tcm ] );
target1Tcm[Tcm_] = 
  Log[Tcm/Tc] + PolyGamma[1/2 + \[CapitalGamma]p/(\[Pi] Tcm)] - 
   PolyGamma[1/2 + \[CapitalGamma]p/(\[Pi] Tc)];

myTrial4Tcm[Mag_?NumericQ, Tcm_?NumericQ] := 
  Parallelize[Sum[sumArg4Tcm[n, Mag, Tcm ] , {n, 0, nMax}] ] // Chop;


(*Equation for Mag*)
sumArg4Mag[n_, Mag_, Tcm_]  = 
  2 Pi Tcm (2 n + 
     1) Pi Tcm (sol4[n, Mag, Tcm ] - 1)/((2 n + 1) Pi Tcm +  
       2 \[CapitalGamma]t )/((2 n + 1) Pi Tcm + 
      2 \[CapitalGamma]t  sol4[n, Mag, Tcm ] );
target1Mag[Tcm_] = 
  Log[Tcm/Ts] + PolyGamma[1/2 + \[CapitalGamma]t/(\[Pi] Tcm)] - 
   PolyGamma[1/2 + \[CapitalGamma]t/(\[Pi] Ts)];
myTrial4Mag[Mag_?NumericQ, Tcm_?NumericQ] := 
  Parallelize[Sum[sumArg4Mag[n, Mag, Tcm ] , {n, 0, nMax}]  ] // Chop;

AbsoluteTiming[FindRoot[{Re[myTrial4Tcm[Mag, Tcm] - target1Tcm[Tcm]], Re[myTrial4Mag[Mag, Tcm] - target1Mag[Tcm]]}, {Mag, 2.28}, {Tcm, 0.235}, 
   WorkingPrecision -> 10]]
```

Running above code gave me an error

The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.

Then I used options WorkingPrecision -> 10 but also gave me same error.

Can someone help me to get the right value?

Comment: `MachinePrecision` corresponds to roughly 15 or 16 digits. 10 is less than that.

Comment: Thanks but when I use WorkingPrecision -> 16 it gives another error FindRoot::precw: The precision of the argument function ({-1.90467+Re[-Log[1.06061 Tcm]+myTrial4Tcm[Mag,Tcm]-PolyGamma[0,1/2+Times[<<2>>]]],PolyGamma[0,128003/205516]+Re[-Log[(50000 Tcm)/51379]+myTrial4Mag[Mag,Tcm]-PolyGamma[0,1/2+Times[<<2>>]]]}) is less than WorkingPrecision (16.`).  I don't know how to fix this issue or how to change the code so as not to encounter such issue?

Comment: `Tc = Rationalize@0.942857` is a machine precision number so the calculations are done with machine precision. To rationalize use `Tc = Rationalize[0.942857, 0]` See documentation for [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rationalize.html)

Comment: @Szabolcs - When calculations are done with `MachinePrecision` numbers, there is no attempt to track or control precision. The result is whatever comes out of the machine calculations and the precision is `MachinePrecision`, i.e., **unknown**. Specifying a `WorkingPrecision` of `10` will result in arbitrary-precision calculations and Mathematica will track and control precision and **attempt** to maintain 10 digits of precision. It will not always succeed in achieving that precision, but in any event `Precision` (or `InputForm` or `FullForm`) will show the precision that was achieved.

Comment: @Bob Hanlon I rationalize all the parameters defined above like you said but also getting the same error so what should I add in the above code to be free from an error and get the right answer?

Comment: Using exact parameters and exact starting values in the `FindRoot` as well as increased `WorkingPrecision`, the parallel computation results in a large number of divisions by zero, e.g., `Power::infy :  "Infinite expression 1/Sqrt[0.*10^1+0.*10^1 I] encountered."` You need to determine why the catastrophic loss of precision and division by zero are occurring.